# How to setup a wired network in the IPv4 network settings?

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup a local network over the CAT5 cable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13025/how-to-setup-a-local-network-over-the-cat5-cable)

I have a problem with setting up the network in the IPv4 wired network settings.
My ISP gave me an IP address that goes like this for my Windows 7 PC

```
IP address: ***.**.**.***
Subnet Mask:***.***.***.*
Default Gateway:***.**.**.*

DNS Server:
Preferred DNS Server:***.**.**.*
Alternate DNS Server:***.***.**.*
```

Please help get my issue solved.
Please tell me how to enter all these details in the Ubuntu settings to get on the network.
I've contacted my ISP and he has no idea of this as Ubuntu is not very commonly used OS on their network.

Comment: Follow this guide http://www.php2s.com/linux/how-to-configure-network-using-cli-ang-gui-in-ubuntu-12-04.html

Comment: mostly the ISPs in India provide IP and DNS automatically instead of a dedicated one... Were you actually given something concrete here?

Comment: @abhishek some ISP (specially cable broadbands) give static ip. The ips are like configuring a bigger lan

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the computer is connected by ethernet cable to the cable modem provided by the ISP, you should see the network manager icon on the right side of the top panel.

Select eth0/1/... (your interface where the cable is plugged in), click edit...

Click add

Connection name: something like Wired Connection.

Check connect automatically.

Click IPv4 Settings tab. Change Method to "Manual." In the table below, under address enter the IP address. Under netmask enter the subnet mask. Under Gateway enter the default gateway. Under DNS servers enter the preferred DNS server a comma (,) and the alternate DNS server. Click Save when done.

See http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/setup-a-permanent-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/ for details.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : Configure network GUI mode

Step 1 : First find out the network interface to configure. Open a terminal and run ifconfig

ifconfig

Result will be something similar to below screenshot.

Step 2 : We will be assigning IP address to eth0 adapter. To do the same Click on “System Setting” and select “Network”

Step 3 : As eth0 is wired connection click on “wired”. Choose “ON” option and click on “Configure” button.

Step 4 : Go to “IPv4 Settings” tab. In case of DHCP / Automatic configuration choose “Automatic (DHCP)” option in “method”

In case of manual configuration select “Manual” option in “method”. Click on “Add” button. Enter IP Address, netmask and gateway information. Also enter DNS Server. In this example I am using google DNS server’s IP.

After finishing it up click on “Save” button.

Step 5: To confirm the setting again run “ifconfig” command and check the “eth0″ interface settings. In case of successful configuration you will see something like below screenshot.

Method 2 : Configure network CLI Mode

Step 1 : First find out the network interface to configure. Open a terminal and run ifconfig

ifconfig

Result will be something similar to below screenshot.

Step 2 : We will be assigning IP address to eth0 adapter. Open a terminal and type

sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

Step 3 : Now you need to add eth0 information in this file.
In case of DHCP / Automatic IP assignment enter following line and save this file.

iface eth0 inet dhcp

In case of manual IP assignment enter following line and save this file.

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1

To configure DNS, enter following command. Remember to run it through “root” user

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolve.conf

Step 4 : Now run following command to start eth0 interface

sudo ifup eth0

Step 5: To confirm the setting again run “ifconfig” command and check the “eth0″ interface settings. In case of successful configuration you will see something like below screenshot.

Source : http://www.techienote.com/2012/04/how-to-configure-network-ubuntu-12-04.html